# 'rails console' command throwing error in Rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, rails-console, javascript

I am using Rails 3.2.9 with ruby 1.9.3 (made default using RVM). From the root directory of my test_app when I executed the command 'rails console' / 'rails c', the following error is showing.

```
rails console
/home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/Rajesh/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /home/local/rajesh.co/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I got the answer for my question.

Just Open the file 'Gemfile' inside the root directory of your application folder, and then paste the below lines there.

```
gem 'execjs'

gem 'libv8'

gem 'therubyracer'
```

After pasting it, just save the file and execute 'bundle update' on the command prompt.

On finishing bundle update successfully, you try running 'rails c' or 'rails console' for taking the rails console. It works!!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

[Source](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/rails-3-1-0rc4-start-server-problem/208127)

Comment: No way!! I installed gem 'therubyracer' and gem 'execjs' and did bundle update. Its not working and the same error is showing again.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, seems like you are using rvm here, so are you sure you bundle the gems in correct rvm package ?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Can you please specify how we need to install  gem 'therubyracer' in my app?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, check this write up about rvm http://keepthingssimple.tumblr.com/post/11274588229/using-rvm-to-keep-things-simple

Answer (score 1):

Install the folowing both:

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Comment: No way!! I installed gem 'therubyracer' and gem 'execjs' and did bundle update. Its not working and the same error is showing again.

Comment: I already did that and I mentioned that in the above comment.

Comment: I mean, just run `bundle install`

Comment: Can you please specify how we need to install gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer' in my app?

Comment: `execjs` gives you the ability to execute javascript, and `therubyracer` gives you the interface from ruby. Both are inter dependencies.